# When is "too much" async and await? Should all methods return Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am building a project and using async and await methods.  Everyone says that async application are built from the ground up, so should you really have any sync methods?  Should all methods you return a Task so you can use the asynchronously?

Lets take a simple example, where by i am using Sql to load data into a collection, here is some code.

This code loads data from a table using `ExecuteQueryAsync` method, the method `GetQuery` constructs the SQL, but calling `GetTableColumns`.  Once the SQL is generated and executed, i loop through the collection and populate each object by calling `GetDataFromReader`.

Should my non async methods, be async?  Am i thinking in too much of a sync-way of programming and missing something?

```
public async Task<ICollection<MyObject>> ExecuteQueryAsync(Module module, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var result = new Collection<MyObject>();
    var query = GetQuery(module);

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            if (parameters != null)
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());

            using (var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await dr.ReadAsync())
                {
                    result.Add(GetDataFromReader(module, dr));
                }

            }
        }

    }

    return result;
}

public string GetQuery(Module module)
{
    return "SELECT " + string.Join(",", GetTableColumns(module).ToArray()) + " FROM [TableA] ";
}

public List<string> GetTableColumns(Module module) 
{
    var columnNames = new List<string>();

    // get all list fields for the module
    var fields = (from a in module.Groups.SelectMany(a => a.Fields) select a).ToList();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (field.Type == FieldType.List) {
            string query = "STUFF(";
            query += "(SELECT ';' + [Value] FROM [TableB] FOR XML PATH(''))";
            query += ", 1, 1, '') AS [" + field.ColumnName + "]";

            columnNames.Add(query);
        } else {
            columnNames.Add("[" + field.ColumnName + "]");
        }
    }

    return columnNames;
}

public MyObject GetDataFromReader(Module module, IDataReader dataReader)
{
    var entity = new MyObject();

    for (var i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        object value = null;
        var fieldName = dataReader.GetName(i);

        if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(i))
        {
            value = dataReader.GetValue(i);
        }

        entity[fieldName] = value;
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: There is no fixed final answer here, it all depends. Short opinion from me; if a method does not use any asynchronous constructs itself, it should not itself be async just to fit some methodology.

Comment: Just a minor note. I like using the callstack and associated tools to debug, and I would hate you for this. Async/Await is easy syntax over quite complex actual code, which may bite you at some point.

Comment: You misunderstood the idea of "async all the way" - it's about letting your whole async *call hierarchy* be async. That is, if you call an asynchronous method, you should yourself be async, and so should your caller, and his caller etc. But there's no reason to code `string.JoinAsync` or something like that - in fact, it's quite counter-productive. If you're only calling synchronous methods, you *shouldn't* be async - that's just misleading.

Answer (score 15):

The philosophy behind "**all async**" is to facilitate [non-blocking I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

That is, your primarily async code can potentially let the environment prioritize how your application or service is being executed and achieve as much parallelized execution as possible in a multi-threaded, multi-process system.

For example, ASP.NET Web API, ASP.NET MVC or even ASP.NET Web Forms (code-behind) can take advantage of **all async** to continue attending Web requests to other users while some async operation is being executed. Thus, even when a Web server like IIS or Katana might limit the number of concurrent requests, async operations are executed in a separate thread from the request thread, and this is allows the Web server to respond to other requests while async operations get a result and they need to continue:

```
// While WhateverAsync is being executed, current thread can be used 
// by a new request and so on.
// Obviously, this will work this way if WhateverAsync actually
// does its work in another thread...
await WhateverAsync();
```

So... do you need to implement everything asynchronously? Even when you return a `Task` you don't need to provide an asynchronous implementation:

```
public Task WhateverAsync()
{
    // This creates a fake Task object which 
    // simulates a Task that has already ended successfully
    // and without creating a child thread!
    // This, this method is a SYNCHRONOUS implementation unless
    // the whole method doesn't execute asynchronous operations.
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

My point of view here is...

- ...implement everything returning a Task and using the `Async` suffix at the end of method's identifiers (`WhateverAsync`, `WhoKnowsAsync`, `DoStuffAsync`...)...
- ...unless you can be sure that the whole method will always execute a very simple things which can't block application/service's thread for a long time (long time can be few miliseconds, now imagine a code which doesn't block main app thread for 100ms whenever some method is called and your code can prioritize executing something while it *awaits* 100ms....). I would include here string manipulation, simple arithmetic operations, configuration methods...

If your code isn't async today, you can turn it into actual async operations without affecting the entire code base, as you only need to change `Task.FromResult<T>(T result)` calls to actually return an unfinished `Task` instance.

At the end of the day, **your methods have an async signature and dependencies on them don't care if they're actually asynchronous, and these method implementations decide what's asynchronous or synchronous instead of giving this responsibility to the caller.**.

Answer (score 6):

If a method has no `async` operations inside it there's no benefit in making it `async`. You should only have `async` methods where you have an `async` operation (I/O, DB, etc.).

If your application has a lot of these I/O methods and they spread throughout your code base, that's not a bad thing. But don't just add the `async` keywords on synchronous methods.

In your specific case `ExecuteQueryAsync` benefits by being async as it allows using `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()`. `GetTableColumns` and `GetDataFromReader` seem to be CPU intensive methods and they don't fit they async-await paradigm.