# Is adding async to a method signature a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In addressing a question about how much to use async/await, i.e. "should all methods return `Task`?", the author of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30661955/2704659), Matías Fidemraizer, claims that, even if your method currently only does synchronous stuff, it should still return a task so if you make it do async stuff later, "you can turn it into actual async operations without affecting the entire code base".  That makes sense, but if I'm actually awaiting something, I have to add `async` to the method signature.  So we're talking about going from:

```
public Task WhateverAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

to

```
public async Task WhateverAsync()
{
    return await AwaitableSomething();
}
```

Is adding `async` to a method signature a breaking change?

Comment: Could you simply return `AwaitableSomething` instead, allowing the caller to await if they please? // Or wrap the function body into `Task.Run(async () => { ... });`? // I have used all methods, including adding `async` to the function definition, I am interested to see what the big reps have to say.

Comment: You specifically link to a post that answers your question, so why are you asking the question?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.  It's only a claim.

Comment: @KDecker Why in the world would you schedule a thread pool thread just to start you asynchronous operation, and why would you wrap the asynchronous operation in a pointless async lambda?  All of those things are only ever pointlessly adding overhead.

Comment: @rory.ap It very *specifically* answers your question.  At best, your question is essentially just asking if that answer is correct or not.  Of course, if you don't believe that person in their answer, why would you trust someone posting an answer here any more?

Comment: The phrase "very specifically" implies that it directly addresses breaking changes.  Can you show me where it does that?  My eyes are starting to hurt, and my browser's "find" feature is no help.  So maybe I am asking if the answer is correct.  So what?  It's good to see that your comments are not lacking their usual derogatory "I'm smarter than everyone" smack, though.

Comment: @rory.ap Sure, it addresses it by saying that the whole *purpose* of the proposal is so that callers won't need to make changes when the method becomes asynchronous.  You said as much yourself.  I apologize for assuming that you knew what a breaking change is when asking if a change is a breaking change, I didn't realize that you needed the term defined for you.  Odd that you criticize me for implying that I'm smarter than everyone simply because I assumed that you were just as smart as I was...

Comment: To be pedantic, a method signature is its name and parameters.

Comment: @KennethK. Don't forget about the return type and attributes.

Comment: @Wazner Sorry, can't tell if you're kidding, but return type is not a part of a method signature, and attributes are often compiler tricks.

Comment: @KennethK. When you define a delegate, you have to specify the return type aswell. You are right that you don't need to return type to uniquely identify a method.

Comment: @Servy Because I am admittedly a novice with TPL.

Answer (score 7):

> even if your method currently only does synchronous stuff, it should still return a task

I disagree. If your method is synchronous, then it should have a synchronous API. If your method is asynchronous, then it should have an asynchronous API.

However, I would agree that synchronous methods should have a `Task`-returning signature **if** they are defined in an interface / base class **and** there is a decent possibility that future implementations / overrides may want to use `await`.

> Is adding async to a method signature a breaking change?

Just adding `async`? No, it is not. Consider the case of a `Task`-returning method defined in an interface: it may be implemented either with or without `async`.

However, there are some possible [differences in semantics](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), as I describe on my blog. The most notable is that the exception handling is different. If you're not careful, a naive synchronous implementation could throw an exception directly, rather than returning a faulted task. As soon as you make that method `async`, the exception would be faulting a task, and no longer thrown directly.

So, it's really a question about possible changes in semantics. I would argue that the naive synchronous semantics were wrong, since the method had an asynchronous signature. E.g., the synchronous method has an asynchronous signature, so it is reasonable for callers to assume that it will catch exceptions and return a faulted task. So, if the synchronous implementations have these (easy-to-cause) bugs, then adding `async` *would* technically be a breaking change.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks a lot for your answer -- quality, as usual.  I have a question as I'm reading through your blog post:  is the code sample under the "Using" heading correct?  The code doesn't contain a "Using" statement and doesn't have to do with downloading (which you indicate).

Comment: I'm wondering what you're seeing. :)  To me, both methods in the code example under "Using" do use `using` and use `HttpClient` to download strings.

Comment: I retract my statement :) On second look it's obviously there.  Can't explain what I thought I saw before.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not (really) a breaking change. Adding an `async` keyword to a method is only a hint to the compiler that it should turn it into an asychronous state machine.

I'm using the following code to check the public signature of a method in LINQPad.

```
var method = typeof(ContainingClass).GetMethod("WhateverAsync");
method.ReturnType.Dump();
method.GetParameters().Length.Dump();
method.GetCustomAttributes().Dump();
```

The first two dumps return the following for both of your methods.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task
0
```

Meaning they return the same type of value and take the same amount of parameters. They do have different attributes though, which is technically a breaking change (but if code does depend on it, it's garbage code).

The first method has no custom attributes, while the 2nd method has the following 2 attributes: `AsyncStateMachineAttribute` and `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`.

Something else you want to be aware of when working with reflection is that adding the `async` keyword to a method, adds a nested private (generated) class to its containing type usually named something along the lines of `<WhateverAsync>d__0`.

Comment: I disagree.  If someone changed a method in one of my classes to async, it's going to screw up every call to it, unless every call is refactored.  If you want it async, make an async version.

Comment: @Trey The *premise* here is that you have a method that returns a `Task` from the start, so it is only ever the private implementation of the method that is changing.

Comment: @Trey -- That's not what the author is talking about.  Not "changing a method to async".  It's already async because it returns a task.  The only question is whether adding the "async" keyword (whose only purpose is to enable an internal `await`) is a breaking change.

Comment: Ahh my bad Rory/Servy. My eyes have opened. :-)